# Dropdown with multiple option does not populate on iPAD

Tags: jakarta-ee, mobile, safari, mobile-safari

I need a solution that how we can fix the multiple drop down for ipad safari browser. 
    I have tried with this piece of code

```
...
<select multiple="multiple" size="5" >
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
</select>
....
```

It shows 0 items and not populating. But normal dropdown without multiple works fine.

Answer (score 0):

which iOS version is your safari running onto?
If you are using jquery mobile, maybe you may try the example in its documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/forms/selects/custom.html (go to multiselect section).